# How to get value of different checkboxes and calculate value of those checked checkboxes and show in the input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little problem with getiing the value of diffrent checkboxes when it is checked. Here is my code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() 
    {
   var waterdm = $('#waterdm').val();
  $("#price").val(waterdm);
 });
});
</script>

<p><input type="checkbox" id="waterdm"  name="waterdm" value="10" />Water Damage</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="screendm" name="screendm" value="20" />Screen Damage</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="Chargerdm" name="Chargerdm" value="30" />Charger Damage</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="hdphdm" name="hdphdm" value="10" />Headphone Damage</p>

<p>
 Calculated Price: <input type="text" name="price" id="price" />
</p>
```

What I want is whenever user check in checkboxes I need to get those value and show the sum of each checkbox value which is checked in to another input box. It Means I need to sum those value of each checkbox
is checked.And when user unchecked any of the checkboxes then that value should subtracted from the that total. I don't have enough experience in jquery. Please help me.

Comment: Question should not change, after answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to iterate over the cheboxes. And `change` event makes more sense when you are talking in terms of checkboxes..

Use `on` to attach events instead of `bind`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // cache the inputs and bind the events
    var $inputs = $('input[type="checkbox"]')
    $inputs.on('change', function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $inputs.each(function() {
        // iterate and add it to sum only if checked
           if(this.checked)
               sum += parseInt(this.value);
        });
        $("#price").val(sum);
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/fFdfK/)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's working but how can I add and subtract value based on checked and unchecked value?

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var waterdm = 0;
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click', function (e) {
         if (this.checked) {
             waterdm += eval(this.value);
         } else {
             waterdm -= eval(this.value);
         }

         $("#price").val(waterdm);
     });
 });
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/vjYx6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var waterdm=0;  
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click',function() 
    {
    waterdm = waterdm+parseInt($(this).val());
    $("#price").val(waterdm);
 });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aQGTY/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() 
    {
        var val = 0;
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
            val+=parseInt($(this).val());
        });
          $("#price").val(val);
     });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/64JQP/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum all checked checkboxes try something like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() 
    {
        var sum = 0;
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
           var val = parseInt($(this).val());
           sum += val;
        });
       $("#price").val(sum);
 });
```